# why request.getParameter("parameter") does not work in JSP?

Tags: jsp

I included a Java helper class in my jsp page : 
    <%@ page import="com.fs.cassandra.IndexHelper" %>

try to use request.getParameter() to control which function I wanna use in IndexHelper class.

[I can't get parameter values in JSP page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJ8Oe.png)

[but I can get them in Java helper class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1sFG.png)

maybe you have to click the link to see pictures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more of a "debugging JSP file with Eclipse" question. Only view you can use while debugging a JSP page with Eclipse is the **Variables** view to inspect the value of any variable.

You can not see the value for example of this expression:

```
request.getParameter("action")
```

just the value of the variable `request`

Try seeing the the variables window instead of expression.

Comment: Thanks. I put my sub URL logic (request.getParameter) into Java file, it works! But still don't know why it's not work in JSP.

Comment: Got the reason! I used request.getParameter("para") == "value", I should have used request.getParameter("para").equals("value"). I used switch ... case ... in Java file, so it worked. I'm new to Java. Thanks very much!

Comment: Good to know you found the reason. Always use **.equals()** method when comparing two strings, actually any object, this is the identical comparison in contrast with reference comparison with **==**. Only time you would want to use **==** is when comparing primitive types like int, double etc.

Answer (score -1):

`request.getParameter("action")`

works only if you have passed the action as a parameter in the url. Try passing a parameter in the url like this

`url?action=1`

Do let us know if your getting the action parameter now.

Comment: That is not a legal URL.

Comment: Agree.. URL should be `url?action=1`

Comment: Thanks. I put my sub URL logic (request.getParameter) into Java file, it works! But still don't know why it's not work in JSP.

Comment: Got the reason! I used request.getParameter("para") == "value", I should have used request.getParameter("para").equals("value"). I used switch ... case ... in Java file, so it worked. I'm new to Java. Thanks very much!